# How does one create an ANTLR grammar for a non-lambda-free language?

Tags: antlr, context-free-grammar

---

I am attempting to mimic the grammar **G** shown below using [ANTLR v4.9.3](https://www.antlr.org) …

[image]

My attempt to do so is shown below …

```
grammar G ;
s : t s | ;
t : 'aaa' t 'bbb' |  ;
```

I invoke the ANTLR Tool as follows …

```
org.antlr.v4.Tool G.g4
```

The tool's response is …

```
The following sets of rules are mutually left-recursive [s]
```

My question is …

> How does one create an ANTLR grammar for grammar **G** ?

---

In order to eliminate the errors, grammar **G** has been updated to …

```
grammar G ;
s : t* EOF ;
t : 'aaa' 'bbb' | 'aaa' t 'bbb' ;
```

---

I am also trying to *programatically* distinguish between strings that are in **L(G)**, and strings that are not in **L(G)** (where **L(G)** is the language generated by grammar **G**).  In the following code, the first string is in **L(G)**, but the second string is not in **L(G)**.

```
    String [] stringArray = { "aaaaaabbbbbbaaabbbaaaaaabbbbbb",
                              "aaabbbaaaaaabbbbbbaaabbbb" } ;
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < stringArray.length ; i ++ )
      {
      CharStream charStream = CharStreams.fromString ( stringArray[i] ) ;
      GLexer lexer = new GLexer( charStream ) ;
      CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream( lexer ) ;
      GParser parser = new GParser( tokens ) ;
      ParseTree tree = parser.s() ;
      } // end for i loop
```

I'd like the code to print messages such as …

```
The string "aaaaaabbbbbbaaabbbaaaaaabbbbbb" is in L(G).
```

… and …

```
The string "aaabbbaaaaaabbbbbbaaabbbb" is not in L(G).
```

How does one *programmatically* distinguish between strings that parse successfully (and are in **L(G)**), and strings that fail to parse successfully (and are not in **L(G)**) ?

---

Comment: Try replacing `s:t s|;` with `s:t* EOF;`

Comment: Replacing `s:t s|;` by `s:t* EOF;` results in `error(153): SimpleGrammar.g4:2:0: rule s contains a closure with at least one alternative that can match an empty string`.

Comment: You have to replace `t : 'aaa' t 'bbb' |  ;` as well; try `t: 'aaa' 'bbb' | 'aaa' t 'bbb';`.

Comment: The second part of this question is now solved. See this [StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22415208/get-rid-of-token-recognition-error).  A `RuntimeException` is thrown, and can be caught, when parsing fails.